# Kali Linux apt-get update Hash sum mismatch error

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kali-linux, apt

I downloaded Offensive Security Kali Linux 2020.2 Virtual Box ova from their website. When I try to update apt, hash sum mismatch error occurs. I tried to update my repositories but to no avail. I have attached the screenshot from [/etc/apt/sources.list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwdoJ.png)
This is my kali version
No LSB modules are available
Distributor ID: Kali
Description: Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release: 2020.2
Codename: kali-rolling

I have also attached the screenshot of the error from sudo apt-get update ["screenshot 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fGtA.png)   ["screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cx74M.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems **gcrypto20** that **SHA256** and **SHA1** have different hash values ​​because they are used in the new Linux. I was able to solve it by the following procedure based on the site posted for reference.

**Solution 1**: Disable WSL 1/2 on windows if not required, This solved my issue and i shifted my docker to Linux.

**Solution 2**: Workaround!

$ **sudo bash**

$ **mkdir /etc/gcrypt**

$ **echo all >> /etc/gcrypt/hwf.deny**

After applying this setting run

$ **sudo apt-get update**

Now the above workaround solves the update issues, as MD5sum matches while updating, but i found my git commands to break and throw errors.

Reference:
https://github.com/ktkr3d/ktkr3d.github.io/issues/1

Comment: I am running a virtualbox Kali VM and this answer fixed this issue for me as well.  How is this related to WSL if i'm running a Virtualbox image?